# Access Denied to Administrator on Domain Controler 2003

Tags: windows-server-2003, permissions

On one of my Domain Controlers, I have a folder that was created by a service. When I try to access it using Administrator credentials I get access denied. Administrator has ownership of the parent directory and full right everywhere else. Attempt to apply to child generates an Access Denied.

This is a temp folder and needs to be emptied at regulr interval. I use to be able to do it but last time I cleared it, I forgot to re-create it and the service did.

How can I reclaim that folder ?

Answer (score 1):

You state that the admin has ownership of the parent directory - have you tried to explicitly take ownership of the folder in question?

Comment: Can't access that folder at all. Clicking/Right Clicking on it grants an instant Access Denied.

Comment: Then you're not logged in as an administrator. An administrator can take ownership of and file/folder on the machine.

Comment: Oh but I am. Logged in as Domain Administrator, this is a DC. Also tried with my own account (member of Administrators) - no luck there either.

Comment: Is the directory encrypted at all?

Comment: No encryption at all.

Comment: The only other time I've seen access denied issues when trying to take ownership is when a file or folder is marked as in use. Try restarting in safe mode and taking ownership there.

Comment: When I do >DIR /AD /Q it show owner of that sub-folder as '...' instead of domain\user

Comment: I will try safe mode. This is a DC and DHCP server. Will have to do it outside work hours. BTW command line ICACLS and TAKEOWN also failed.

Comment: If you do it safe mode, check to make sure the service in question is stopped as well. Does the service run under domain credentials or the system account?

Comment: I disabled the services and rebooted, was not fast enough with the F8, it booted normally and the sub-folder was gone! Was able to re-create the folder, re-enabled the services, rebooted and everything is now fine! Still not sure how/what/why it happen but I am very relieved it is solved. I appreciate your assistance. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Take owership of the subfolder. If the service breaks inheritance and sets a new owner, then you'll need to explicitly take ownership of the troublesome folder and check the box that applies it to all contained objects. Then, change the permissions like you would for anything else.

Comment: Can't take ownership - I tried!

Answer (score 0):

Take ownership of the parent folder (that you can access), and tick the box to replace the owner on subcontianers and objects.

(Properties -> Security -> Advanced -> Owner -> Edit)

One that's done, you'll be able to change the permissions to allow Administrators Full Control.

Comment: Tried that, took ownership of parent (which as Administrator I already had). When I apply to children I get an Access Denied for that subfolder.